# HttpClient is slow when called in an https context in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, https

I've got a server using Asp.Net Core, and I am having trouble with delays when using HTTPS.
When only fetching a few images, each request takes around 20ms to process. However when I make 125 requests simultaneously they slow down to 30-80ms (acceptable) when using HTTP, and down to 130-850ms (unacceptable) when using HTTPS.

I've done some debugging and the slowdown occurs when my server makes the http call to the WMS server.

Adding a custom socket handler cut the delay down from 4000-6000ms to the current 130-850ms so that helped a lot, but the delay is still a bit much.

PS: The server will do a bit more than simply proxying the queries, so I can't simply use a dedicated proxy server for that role.

Here's a minimal example of the server code:

```
using System.Diagnostics.Tracing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;

using var socketHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler()
{
    PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
    PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
    MaxConnectionsPerServer = 1,
};

using var httpClient = new HttpClient(socketHandler);

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(httpClient);

var app = builder.Build();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();


[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WMSController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly HttpClient Client;
    private readonly string BaseUrl;

    public WMSController(HttpClient client)
    {
        Client = client;
        BaseUrl = "http://my-local-hostname.company.internal:10301/WMS";
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "WMS")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetWms()
    {
        var query = HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Value;

        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        var response = await Client.GetAsync(BaseUrl + query); // This is the slow part.
        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss} - {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} - {HttpContext.Connection.Id}");
        stopwatch.Reset();
        var image = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

        return new FileContentResult(image, "image/jpeg");
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as HTTPS is concerned: try caching the server's certificate as a trusted root in your operating system, and maybe disable revocation checking for that URL also.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I've already set it as trusted root on my computer.

Comment: Also what size (bandwidth) is your network connection, what is the round-trip ping time to the server, and does the server and client support HTTP/2 or TLS 1.3?

Comment: The client, and both servers are all on the same physical machine (I've also tried with different machines). The round-trip ping time is <1ms. Both the client and proxy server support both HTTP/2 and TLS 1.3.

Comment: Ah that's a whole different ball game if it's all local. Most likely then that there is some inefficiency elsewhere in the ASP stack (or in the other source server app you are using), or there is another proxy or antivirus interfering

Comment: why you are injecting `httpClient` as singleton? can you create new httpClient per request? You have set `MaxConnectionsPerServer` to `1` which is sequentially downloading the file. If you make new httpClient per request it will make multiple parallel connections.

Comment: Because you're not supposed to create a new HttpClient for each request. Doing so alwo makes it a lot slower.

Comment: `MaxConnectionsPerServer` definitely should not be set

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of efficiencies you can make.

- Use a global `HttpClient` and handler, so that requests to the same server can multiplex. This also prevents socket exhaustion.

```cs
static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new SocketsHttpHandler()
{
    PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
    PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
});
```

- Use `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` so that only the headers are buffered, otherwise the full response has to be buffered.
  Note that the timings will now only be until the headers are received.

```
[HttpGet(Name = "WMS")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetWms()
{
    var query = HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Value;

    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    using var response = await Client.GetAsync(BaseUrl + query, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss} - {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} - {HttpContext.Connection.Id}");
    stopwatch.Reset();

    var image = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    return new FileContentResult(image, "image/jpeg");
}
```

- A further improvement may only work if your use case supports it: feed the response as a stream directly to `FileStreamResult`

```
[HttpGet(Name = "WMS")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetWms()
{
    var query = HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Value;

    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    // NO using, otherwise stream gets disposed
    var response = await Client.GetAsync(BaseUrl + query, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss} - {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} - {HttpContext.Connection.Id}");
    stopwatch.Reset();

    var image = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    return new FileStreamResult(image, "image/jpeg");
}
```

Comment: I'm already using only single instance of HttpClient.
Changing the call to SendAsync instead of GetAsync, did not affect the timings.

Comment: I find that difficult to believe. There must be some measurable difference between `ResponseHeadersRead` and `ResponseContentRead`

Comment: I wish there was a measurable difference, but sadly both versions take the same amount of time.